# UPDATE to Access database fails when Replication ID used in WHERE clause

Tags: python, sql-update, execute, pyodbc

I have a database file which I want to modify. Therefore I use pyodbc with the following code:

```
import pyodbc

myDbFile = r"D:\Users\Tobias\Documents\database.db"
myPass = u'*****'

cnx = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=%s;PWD=%s;Charset=utf-8' % (myDbFile, myPass))
cursor = cnx.cursor()

# reading any database entry
cursor.execute('SELECT ID, Title, Tag FROM Dox')
mydata = cursor.fetchall()
print mydata[34]
# -> returns ('010CC005-4A8A-4AB3-8B98-E431D3BB328B', u'itemTitle', None)

# The following line works fine
cursor.execute('UPDATE Dox SET Tag=30 WHERE Title = ?', u'itemTitle')

# But this doesn't -> nothing is changed
cursor.execute('UPDATE Dox SET Tag=30 WHERE ID = ?', '010CC005-4A8A-4AB3-8B98-E431D3BB328B')

cnx.commit()
cnx.close()
```

I have absolutely no idea why the identification by 'ID' does not work. Do you have any hints for me?

Answer (score 0):

Access can be a bit fussy when it comes to specifying Replication ID values and I was able to recreate your issue as posted. However, wrapping the ID value in curly brackets worked for me:

```python
cursor.execute('UPDATE Dox SET Tag=30 WHERE ID = ?', '{010CC005-4A8A-4AB3-8B98-E431D3BB328B}')
```